# Who am I and how did I die?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Protected from death by Oath.
>
> My father being the Father of men.
>
> Brother mischieved by brother,
>
> Led to one another.

**Who am I? Who killed me and how?**

Comment: "Brother mischieved by brother" reminds me of a Marvel movie...

Comment: @Phylyp I thought of that in the beginning, but then I remembered that Thor didn't get killed by Loki...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Mischieved doesn't necessarily mean killed, right?

Comment: Added the knowledge tag, since I (and many others) couldn't have solved it without using external sources.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> [Baldr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldr)

Explanation:

Protected from death by Oath

> I actually found [this](http://web.mit.edu/norvin/www/somethingelse/baldr.html): Frigg exacted an oath from fire and water, iron and all kinds of metals, stones, earth, trees, ailments, beasts, birds, poison and serpents, that they would not harm Baldr

My father being the Father of Men

> Baldr is the son of Odin

Brother mischieved by brother

> Höðr was mischieved by Loki into killing his brother Baldr

Led to one another

> I think this is related to how Höðr was **led** by loki to kill Baldr

Comment: Goodjob! Got all the points spot on. Indeed Baldr's mother frigg Made every living thing take an oath not to harm baldr. Except for the small mistletoe because of it's innocence. With that knowledge Loki forged a spear from the mistletoe and made the blind hodr throw it at baldr. little did hodr know it was made of mistletoe and so killing baldr

Comment: Answerers putting their solutions in spoiler tags is of little benefit if people then give the answer away in the comments.  Try using [ROT-13](http://www.rot13.com/) encoding or similar to preserve the mystery for future would-be solvers. :)

Answer (score 12):

You are

> The Biblical figure Abel

And you were killed by

> Your brother Cain, with a rock.

Explanation:

Protected from death by Oath

> "And the Lord set a mark upon Cain so that whoever found him would not slay him." (Genesis 4:15)

My father being the Father of Men

> Cain and Abel were the sons of Adam, the first human.

Brother mischieved by brother

> Abel was murdered by his brother.

Led to one another

> Not sure about this one but it may refer to how Cain led Abel out to a field, where he then killed him.

Comment: I actually really like this answer, but it is not the answer i had in mind while writing. it fits pretty good tho so thats why i will give you a hint. Try a religion which originates to before christianity took over europe

Comment: I thought this too

Comment: The story of Cain & Abel is from Judaism, not Christianity. Judaism predates the earliest records of Norse Mythology by perhaps a thousand years. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_history and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Norse_religion#Archaeological_and_toponymic_evidence

Comment: im not stating any of those things, im simply stating look for a religion that was in europe before chrisitanity took over. Was judaism in europe before the pagan religiong?